# How to read elevation data from WMS response?

Tags: c#, elevation, wms

I am trying to get elevation data from the tile received from [USGS](http://imselev.cr.usgs.gov/WMS_Capabilities/USGS_EDC_Elev_NED/capabilities_1_3_0.xml) server.

I query the data using Image Format image/Png. When I read the data I get color values. I need to know how to read the elevation values from it. Is there any documentation or sample available.

Answer (score 1):

If the WMS service supports it, you can make a WMS GetFeatureInfo request. That returns attribute value(s) at a coordinate, for example where a user clicks.

If you need more that a point elevation value you should look for a WCS service providing elevation data. WCS is the OGC's Web Coverage Service and serves data values rather than colour values, queryable by band, bounding box, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The elevation layers are unfortunately all set to queryable="0", so they don't support WMS GetFeatureInfo Request, only the ***_footprint layers are accepting it.

The Color Value of the image only represents a classification of the real elevation values, so you might not be able to calculate an elevation out of the color value, if you don know how it is classified, and even then it will be hard to determin an exact value.

Doesn't actually make much sense, if the USGS publishes elevation data over a not queryable WMS Layer, because its only a stupid image of greyscale foam....:(